# Cancel firebase notification already sent from server

Tags: php, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

the behavior is:

user A makes an action in web application, creates a notification and server send this notification to user on device B.

user on device B receive the notification.

Then user A removes the action (i.e user upload and publish video then delete video after some seconds...)

The question is, there is a way to cancel or remove notifications once notification has been sent?

Code for send messages from server to device:

```
<?php       
$factory = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount(...);
$messaging = $factory->createMessaging();
$message = CloudMessage::withTarget("token",$token)
            ->withNotification(Notification::create($title, $body));        
$messaging->send($message);
```

There is any $messaging->delete($message); ???

Comment: Please, show the code you tried

Comment: It's possible to cancel a message already sent?